# Paypal button event onshippingChange is not working at all can somebody tell me why?

Tags: javascript, paypal, sdk

Can somebody tell me why? This is a simple integration of paypal sdk for javascript. And It is working fine except that the event bellow onShippingChange is never fired. I've searching this for 2 days now. I need to update my price according to the user address.

```
    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXXXXXX"> // Required. Replace SB_CLIENT_ID with your sandbox client ID.
  </script>
  
   <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      console.log('createOrder ' + data);       

      return actions.order.create({
        application_context : {
            shipping_preference: 'SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS'
        },purchase_units: [{
          shipping: {
            address: {
                address_line_1: '555 example bs',
                admin_area_2: 'San bastard',
                admin_area_1: 'CA',
                postal_code: '95111',
                country_code: 'CA'
            }
          },
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    console.log('onApprove ' + data);
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    },
    onClientAuthorization: (data) => {
                console.log('onClientAuthorization - you should probably inform your server about completed transaction at this point', data);
                this.showSuccess = true;
    },
    onShippingChange: (data, actions) => {
// this event is never fired no matter what I do
                console.log('onShippingChange - Shipping information have changed', data, actions);
    },
    onCancel: (data, actions) => {
                console.log('OnCancel', data, actions);
    },
    onError: err => {
                console.log('OnError', err);
    },
    onClick: (data, actions) => {
                console.log('onClick', data, actions);
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution of this question first of the shippings fees can only be managed after you enable it on your account (Login to PayPal >> Hover over to the profile name >> Account Settings >> Shipping >> Here you can create shipping profiles as per your requirements.) it will be available only for customer who pay from a paypal account. For any other payment you won't be able to manage it.

Regards